# How to save screenshot from Unity to azure storage?

Tags: c#, azure, unity-game-engine

I am working on a unity project and I need to save a certain screenshot from my game to a container in azure storage.
I already configured my azure account and created the container.

I managed to take the screenshot and save it in a directory on my computer but whenever I try to save it to my storage I cant because it does not found it. I go to that directory and I can see the screenshot.

This is how I do the screenshot part:

```
public void TappedCaptureScreenshot()
    {
        string filename = string.Format("{0}.png", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-ff"));
        Debug.Log("aca estoy 0 " + filename);
        localPath = Screenshot.Capture(filename);
        Debug.Log("local path " + localPath);
        isCaptured = true;
        //label.text = "Capture as: " + localPath;
    }
```

This is how I save the picture:

```
 public void TappedSave()
    {  
        byte[] imageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(localPath);
        PutImage(imageBytes);
    }

private void PutImage(byte[] imageBytes)
    {
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(localPath);
        Debug.Log("Aca estoy 2 " + filename);
        //label.text = "Put " + filename;
        StartCoroutine(blobService.PutImageBlob(PutImageCompleted, imageBytes, container, filename, "image/png"));
    }
```

Then whenever I clic a certain button, both functions are called.
This is the error I get:
FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "C:..\20-02-23-21-12-59-06.png"

I think the error has something to do with image bytes but I do not know why. Any suggestions?

Comment: Obviously, `C:..\20-02-23-21-12-59-06.png` is not a correct file path.  Did you get the error from `string filename = Path.GetFileName(localPath);` ? Debug your application to see what the `localPath`'s value is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do not know what the problem was but I solved putting both functions in different buttons and not in the same one.